# How to update navigation header from screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
react-native version 0.62
```

I am making a quiz app and on every new question(a new quiz screen, `QuestionScreen.js`), I want to update a label in the navigation bar which is declared in `App.js`
In `App.js`, the problem here is I don't know how to pass the state `questionIndex` to `HomeScreen` or `QuestionScreen`, normally I thought this would be using props like `<Question questionIndex={questionIndex}>`. I tried to pass them in `options` but that doesn't seem to work...

```
const App = () => {
  const [questionIndex, setQuestionIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'
      > 
      <Stack.Screen 
      name='Home'
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        title:''
    }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
      name='QuestionScreen'
      component={QuestionScreen} 
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
          headerRight: ()=>(<HeaderRight pageIndex={questionIndex}/>),
           headerRightContainerStyle: {
                        alignItems: "flex-end",
                        paddingRight: 25
            },
      })}
    />


function HeaderRight(props) {
  return (
      <Text>{props.pageIndex}/{questions.length-1}</Text>
    );
}
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} >
    <ScrollView>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> 
      //here I'm unable to retrieve the questionIndex props.
      //tried navigation.getParams("questionIndex") or route.params
      
      navigation.navigate('QuestionScreen', {
          pageIndex: 0
      })
    }>
```

In `QuestionScreen.js`

```
function QuestionScreen({route, navigation, options}) {

    const { pageIndex } = route.params;
```

[Full code here on github]https://github.com/liaoxsong/expofirst
I am a newbie to react-native and I come from native mobile development, this Stack.Navigator api looks weird, can't I just manage the navigation header from the screen component itself? That would make things easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63364112/2382964 .... explore this

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to customize the default header given by react navigation, what you can do is disabling the header and creating your own custom header.

disable header by giving prop headerMode={"none"} in createStackNavigator and have your own custom header on top,

to disable header docs : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headermode

Comment: where exactly do I put this `headerMode={'none'}`?..and ideally I want the custom header to stay fixed when one screen moves to next, and this custom header is just another view right.. so it will be animiated

Comment: To disable header in stack navigator do like this `<Stack.Navigator> <Stack.Screen name="Home" headerMode={'none'} component={Home} /> </Stack.Navigator>`. And You can have custom header like this `<View style={Style.navigation}> <View style={Style.navLeft}><BackButton/></View><View style={Style.navMiddle}><Title/></View><View style={Style.navRight}><ICon/></View></View>`